# How can I move a Windows forms shapeContainer and all shapes contained within it

Tags: c#, windows, forms, containers

I want to create an image made from several lines, ovals and rectangles. I think the best way of doing this will be to add them all as part of a shapeContainer and then I will need to add multiple instances of these images on my form.

I have created the image with no issues and added all shapes to a single shapeContainer. I now want the ability to be able to position this image anywhere in the form. I thought the logical way of doing this would be to just position the shapeContainer and because all shapes are positioned relative to their parent (the shapeContainer) the entire image should move with it.

However when I call the position function on the shapeContainer, nothing moves. I call this function from the form class (the form is the parent of the shapeContainer). The shapeContainer has its location set in the form.designer.cs file to point (0,0). I changed that but nothing happened.

How am I meant to set the position of a shapeContainer, and hence all shapes within it?

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to move some control with the mouse?did you use the VB container?

Comment: @TaW Not necessarily move it with just the mouse but also with code. Haven't used a VB container, how does it differ from a ShapeContainer?

Comment: Isn't ShapeContainer from a VB power pack?

Comment: Yes. It showed up in the toolbox in the designer when I wanted to draw shapes so that is what I have been using for shapes (ovalshape, lineshape etc)